# Faceted classification - Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to build a faceted classification using Spring Data Mongo and I'm confused on how to use `Aggregation.facet` method.

As I'm trying to figure out how the thing work I'm using twice the same `FacetOperation` and I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'producer.fundings'!`. This `FacetOperation` alone in the `Aggregation` works fine!

```
FacetOperation fo1 = facet(
        unwind("producer.fundings"),
        project().and("producer.fundings.type").as("type").and("producer.fundings.acronym").as("name"),
        group("name", "type").count().as("count"),
        project("count").and("_id.name").as("name").and("_id.type").as("type").andExclude("_id")
    ).as("fundingAcronymFacet");

    FacetOperation fo2 = facet(
        unwind("producer.fundings"),
        project().and("producer.fundings.type").as("type").and("producer.fundings.acronym").as("name"),
        group("name", "type").count().as("count"),
        project("count").and("_id.name").as("name").and("_id.type").as("type").andExclude("_id")
    ).as("fundingNameFacet");

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(fo1,fo2);
AggregationResults<FacetClassification> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "observations", FacetClassification.class);
List<FacetClassification> facet = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

So either I'm not using the facet method well and only one call is needed to create different facet. This would looks like how it is implemented in the MongoDB API: [$facet (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)
Or I need to chain `facet` call to create the different facets of my classification and need to know what happens after the first call and why the exact same reference is not found.

The documentation only provides examples that create one facet and could'nt find any example elsewhere: [Spring Data Mongo Faceted Classification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.facet).

related to : [Using multiple facets in MongoDB Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327613/using-multiple-facets-in-mongodb-spring-data)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain multiple facet operation using the `and()` and `.as()`methods. The example should look like this to create two different facet in the same aggregation operation:

```
FacetOperation fo1 = facet(
        unwind("producer.fundings"),
        project().and("producer.fundings.type").as("type").and("producer.fundings.acronym").as("name"),
        group("name", "type").count().as("count"),
        project("count").and("_id.name").as("name").and("_id.type").as("type").andExclude("_id")
).as("fundingAcronymFacet")
        .and(unwind("producer.fundings"),
                project().and("producer.fundings.type").as("type").and("producer.fundings.acronym").as("name"),
                group("name", "type").count().as("count"),
                project("count").and("_id.name").as("name").and("_id.type").as("type").andExclude("_id")
        ).as("fundingNamesFacet");
```